# For scraping data, how do you navigate to the link you created? Then, how do you scrape data from the new page?

Tags: r, web-scraping

This is the sample code that I've created. I've been able to create a new link, but I'm confused how to follow the link in and scrape data from the followed link.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

url<-"https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data%20analyst&l=San%20Diego%2C%20CA&vjk=0c2a6008b4969776"
page<-xml2::read_html(url)#function will read in the code from the webpage and break it down into different elements (<div>, <span>, <p>, etc.

#get job title
title<-page %>%
  html_nodes(".jobTitle") %>%
  html_text()
  
#get company Location
loc<-page %>%
  html_nodes(".companyLocation") %>%
  html_text()

#job snippet
page %>%
  html_nodes(".job-snippet") %>%
  html_text()

#Get link 
desc<- page %>%
  html_nodes("a[data-jk]") %>%
  html_attr("href") 

# Create combine link 
combined_link <- paste("https://www.indeed.com", desc, sep="")
```

How do I follow the combined link and scrape data from the new page and is it possible to do it without using a function?

Comment: Can't you use `read_html(combined_link)` like you did the first time? Perhaps I'm confused about what you're intending to do here.

Comment: Thanks, yes I've tried that but i get an error saying 
"Error: `x` must be a string of length 1".

Comment: page1 <-  html_session(combined_link[[1]]) 
page1 %>%
  html_nodes(".iCIMS_JobContent, #jobDescriptionText") %>%
  html_text()     #this code works, but now I'd like to create a function #that will  extract the content for each page using this info

Comment: Have you looked at `desc`? It sounds like it isn't a single string

Comment: You're right, I'm getting 16 strings. I need to create some sort of loop function to get each string out from each new webpage

Comment: `ret <- lapply(paste0("https://www.indeed.com", desc), xml2::read_html)` will return a list of page-returns, for which you can individually scrape data you need.

Comment: This is the function I was looking for !!! Thank you !!!

Comment: This is embarrassing, but I'm not used to working with lists of lists. Would you mind showing me how to get the titles of each of the 16 pages from the "ret" variable.

Comment: Don't be embarrassed! Not sure exactly (I'm not running your code), but perhaps `lapply(setNames(nm=paste0("https://www.indeed.com", desc)), xml2::read_html)` for the original call, or if you're already created `ret`, can you just `names(ret) <- desc` or similar? (I'm assuming that the title is apparent in the elements of `desc`. If not, then that's just a different scraping question, and ... unfortunately I haven't run your code and cannot at the moment ...)